# How do I assign SQL queries to variables (num & den) and then divide them?

Tags: sql

I have to assign a SQL query to a numerator and a denominator and then divide the result. The logic required is as follows:

Num:

```
    Study Count where reliability[flag]=1 
    AND reliability[status]="On Time" 
    OR reliability[status] = "Planned On Time"
```

Den:

```
    Study Count where reliability[flag]=1
```

(Num/Den)/100

Comment: I've gone  ahead and removed the tag spam. [Edit] your question and tag correctly please.

Comment: I doubt if you need to do that , please add sample data and expected outcome as text.

Comment: What is your tables' structure?

Comment: Kind of `select 100.0*count(case .. end)/count(case .. end) ..` i.e. conditional aggregation.

Comment: A [mcve] is a great start when asking SQL questions.

Answer (score 0):

You can use case statements to find the counts that meet each of the conditions then apply the division in a single query as shown below

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN (reliability_flag = 1 AND reliability_status = 'On Time') OR reliability_status = "Planned On Time"
                      THEN 1
                ELSE 0
           END) * 100.0
       /
       SUM(CASE WHEN reliability_flag = 1 THEN 1
                ELSE 0
           END))
FROM table_name
```

Or, you can find the counts separately using two independent queries and divide the results of the two queries to find the final result .

```
SELECT
   (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM table_name
    WHERE (reliability_flag = 1 AND reliability_status = 'On Time')
        OR reliability_status = "Planned On Time") * 100.0
   /
   (SELECT COUNT(*)
    FROM table_name
    WHERE reliability_flag = 1)
```